# Reading Plain Certificates in Java

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, client-certificates

i am trying to connect to kafka using ssl certificates. below are the files i have

```
ca.crt
ca.p12
ca.password
```

and here's how i'm providing these certs in consumer properties.

```
propsMap.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_TYPE_CONFIG, "PKCS12");
propsMap.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, caP12Location);
propsMap.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, caPassword);
```

when connecting i am getting below exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to load SSL keystore /etc/kafka/client-certs/ca.p12 of type PKCS12
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:172)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:157)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:73)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:105)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:734)
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to load SSL keystore /etc/kafka/client-certs/ca.p12 of type PKCS12
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory$FileBasedStore.load(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:377)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory$FileBasedStore.<init>(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:349)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory.createTruststore(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:322)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory.configure(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:168)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.instantiateSslEngineFactory(SslFactory.java:136)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.configure(SslFactory.java:93)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:168)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory$FileBasedStore.load(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:374)
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    ... 48 common frames omitted
```

my question is

1. why it's looking for keystore password. i am not using any keystore.
2. do i have to use a keystore here? can i not use plain certificate files?

Comment: Java uses a special case (i.e. a subset) of keystore for truststore -- it reads the keystore format and selects the 'trusted' cert(s) in it. For JKS format you can sometimes read cert(s) without the password, but PKCS12 format no. Also unless your PKCS12 was created _by_ Java (e.g. `keytool` or `keystore-explorer`) the certs in it won't be considered trusted by the 'sun' provider. I don't use kafka but [this](https://codingharbour.com/apache-kafka/using-pem-certificates-with-apache-kafka/) asserts you can use PEM (non-keystore) files.

Comment: In short, PKCS#12 **is** a keystore format. Java can use certs (or rather `Set<TrustAnchor>`) internally, but it makes sense for frameworks to use keystores.